# How to perform segue when a cell is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I am very new to Swift, and i'm wondering how to perform segue when user tap one of the table view cells.

In UITableViewCell controller I tried to type `performSegue` and wait for hints by Xcode like below

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
   if selected {
      performSegue() <- HERE
   }
   super.setSelected(selected, animated: true)
}
```

I couldn't find any hints, so I think i misunderstand the concept.

Is there any way to perform segue when a cell is tapped? And I also want to send some data to the destination, so it'll be great if you can provide a way to send data to the destination as well.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Segues In Code:**

So firstly a good way of performing something when a cell (table view cell) is tapped is using the `tableView didSelectRowAt` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Place code you want to be performed when a cell is tapped inside of here, for example:
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender Any?) // Make sure your identifier makes sense and is preferably something memorable and easily recognisable.
}
```

- The segue `identifier` is just so that swift/interface builder knows which segue you are referring to.
- The `sender` is the thing which caused the segue to be performed an example of this is a `UIButton`.

Next you will need to prepare for the segue inside of the View Controller which is being segued to using the following method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Do any required setup for this segue such as passing in data loading required views and specifying how you want the segue to be performed such as if you want the view to be pushed, or presented as a popover etc... for example:
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewController { // Downcast to the desired view controller.
    // Configure the view controller here...
    }
}
```

NOTE: You can also create segues in interface builder by control dragging from something such as a `UIButton` and then setting the segue identifier in the Attributes Inspector in the panel on the right:

**Segues In Interface Builder:**

- Control drag and this menu will pop up for you to select the presentation:
  [image: Action Segue Screenshot]
- Then set an `identifier` for the segue in the Attributes panel in the right side of the screen:
  [image: Segue Attributes Inspector Screenshot]
- Finally `prepare` for the segue inside of the view controller which will be segued to in code just like you do when creating a segue in code.

This video might also be useful to you to gain more clarification on segues and how to perform and prepare for them etc:
https://youtu.be/DxCydBmOqXU

Comment: Can I still override tableView didSelectRowAt function when i'm inheriting UIViewController? When can I override it?

Comment: If your inheriting from a plain UIViewController then you can not override the function as there is no need to. Instead make the class conform to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Comment: Ok, I'll try it.

Comment: To do this:
ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
The first item (Sorry I’m not sure what the correct name for it is) after the “:” is what the class inherits from the following items is what the class confirms to
NOTE:
UITableViewDelegate - handles things such as touch events etc
UITableViewDataSource - manages the data which is used to populate the table view

Comment: I tried override the didSelectRowAt, but xcode says Method does not override any method from its superclass. I have inherited the protocols you mentioned.

Comment: Yeh that’s because the override keyword is not required if you are not overriding any methods from the view controllers super class which when inheriting from a UIViewController you are not doing.
The only thing you need to do if you have not already is confirm to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.
Like so:
ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: One other thing you need to do which I completely forgot about is you need to set the table view’s delegate and date source to the current view controller (self)
You can do this in viewDidLoad() {
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235525/discussion-between-noby-and-demented07).